# Drawing an arc in C++ Graphics.h

Tags: c++, bgi, winbgi

I'm using graphics.h in order to start with a bit of graphic in C++, but when I run the code the program crash. I'm using CodeBlocks as a compiler and Windows 8.1 as an operating system. What should I do in order to make it works? 
Here is the code:

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT;
    int gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    arc(200, 200, 0, 130, 50);

    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: If you are using the old Borland grahpics.h I don't believe it will work with windows 8.1.  It was written for win95/98 and a real dos prompt.

Comment: You can't make it work. Forget about graphics.h

Comment: Oh my, `graphics.h`. It's been 20 years since I have seen it last time. Are you an archaeologist?

Comment: I believe you need to downgrade to a mingw release from 10+ years ago. The latest release of winbgim was from 2005. http://winbgim.codecutter.org/

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773892/how-to-solve-codeblocks-unable-to-run-a-graphics-c-program-properly/57507125#57507125), it may help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What should I do to make it works?"

1) Forget about graphics.h it is obsolete.

2) Get yourself a modern compiler (for example; Clang 7.1, GCC 8.3 or Visual Studio 2017).

3) Pick a modern graphics library. [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org) and [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org) are popular options.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to BGI's `graphics.h` is TX Library. See here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/txlib. The docs are here: http://storage.ded32.net.ru/Lib/TX/TXUpdate/Doc/HTML.ru). The docs are currently in Russian.

A simple example:

```
#include "TXLib.h"

int main()
{
    txCreateWindow (800, 600);

    txLine   (320, 290, 320, 220);
    txLine   (320, 290, 280, 350);
    txLine   (320, 290, 360, 350);
    txLine   (320, 230, 270, 275);
    txLine   (320, 230, 400, 220);
    txCircle (320, 190, 30);

    txSelectFont ("Times New Roman", 60);
    txTextOut (240, 400, "Hello, world!");

    txArc (100, 100, 300, 200, 45, 270);

    return 0;
}
```