# how to solve codeblocks unable to run a graphics c program properly

Tags: c, winapi, bgi

I had setup codeblocks for graphics programming. like I install winbgim file. and done other setup in the codeblocks linker setting. but when I ran a program like this

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

 main(void) {
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode;
    int x1 = 200, y1 = 200;
    int x2 = 300, y2 = 300;
    system("cls");

    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

it did not run as I expected .the process returned by 0xc0000005 . and also the winbgi window did not opened. so plz help me to out of this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can get and use the header file <graphics.h> in my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program)

Comment: And what was the value in `gdriver`, `gmode` *after* the function call

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Did you download WinBGIm library from its [website](http://www.codecutter.net/tools/winbgim/)?

If yes, then the header files `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` have a bug. On line 302, of each of those files, replace `right = 0` with `top = 0`.

But, then the problem is the library itself was built using the "buggy" header files, so:

- you either need to build the library from the source code yourself, or
- you need to download corrected library which was already built by someone else who faced this issue. Fortunately, I found such a library [here](https://tejassproxy.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-setup-winbgim-library-in.html) (Link in Step 2).

So, now if you put the corrected files (header files as well as the library), in the target folders and re-build, the program should not crash.

Answer (score -3):

Download WinBGIm. CLICK TO DOWNLOAD. Downloading from other website may not work.

Extract it.

Open `info.txt` for linker options and more information.

Copy `MinGW` folder to your `Code::Blocks` installation directory. Default `Code::Blocks` installation directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks`. There will be `MinGW` folder already. Copying new `MinGW` folder only adds some library (`libbgi.a`) and header (`winbgim.h`, `graphics.h`) files in that directory. To manually add files, copy `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` files in include folder of your compiler directory which is `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW`. And copy `libbgi.a` to `lib` folder of your compiler directory.

Open `Code::Blocks`. Open `Settings >> Compiler >> Linker Settings`. Click Add button in link libraries part and browse and select `libbgi.a` file you just copied to `MinGW` folder.

In right part (i.e. other linker options) paste commands `–lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32`

Click OK.

Comment: try to format and structure your post. Right now it's a wall of text and it's unreadable