# Why my C++ Graphics Program is not showing any output with g++ compiler?

Tags: c++, g++, bgi, winbgi

I have written a code in C++, which is given below. The program is compiling successfully. But, when I'm trying to run the .exe file, then I am not getting the desired output.

My Code:

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>

int main( )
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, (char*)"");
    setcolor(BLUE);
    line(100, 100, 200, 200);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

I am using the following command in Windows Command Prompt to compile the program:

```
g++ -m32 -o trial trial.cpp -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 "C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libbgi.a"
```

To run my .exe file:
`trial` for cmd and `./trial` in powershell.

But after this I am not getting any output. Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: `start /wait trial.exe` `echo %errorlevel%` what output does running this gives? Is it non-zero? Try adding `-lgraph` linker directive. Also no need of writing `(char*)""`, simply replacing it will `NULL` should do the same.

Comment: I'd argue that the root problem is the use of antiquated and obsolete libraries for the graphics. While modern libraries are often more complex to set up (but not by much), they are also more powerful and flexible, and (most importantly) more *modern* and up to date with modern environments.

Comment: @brc-dd I have tried adding ```-lgraph``` to the linker directive but, this error is occuring ```C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgraph
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: @brc-dd I have also tried the command ```start /wait trial.exe```,  ```echo %errorlevel%```, but there is no output. Only a blank terminal appears and then disappears simultaneously for the first command. For the second command it returns -1073741819, which is non-zero.

Comment: Did you consider using a cross-platform graphical library such as [Qt](https://qt.io/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [FOX](https://fox-toolkit.org/), or [libSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) ? Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info, so compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :**  You are missing `-L` before path pointing to your `libbgi.a` library. More details are available here : [Directory Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

---

Literally no one uses `graphics.h` these days. There are much better alternatives, as pointed by others.

But there are a lot of questions on StackOverflow referring to error code `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)` on using `WinBGIm`, not having any answer. Hence I'd like to post one here.

This error code is generated on segmentation fault. There may be many factors causing it, but with `WinBGIm`, it's generally due to a bug in the library itself.

To make it work you have to change `line 302` of the `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` (downloaded from the [official source](https://winbgim.codecutter.org/)) from

```cpp
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
```

to

```cpp
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
```

The difference should appear trivial; earlier there was a typo as there were two arguments named `right`.

---

Bug-free libraries and headers are available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1iuPRY6vIm5WjNNQUxzajVmcW8&usp=sharing).

Actually I found a similar answer now. Future readers may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507125/11613622).

Comment: I have corrected this typo already and after correcting this only I have posted this question here. So I don't think this error is due to the typo.

Comment: Moreover this code runs fine in **Codeblocks 17.12**, as one of my friend have run this code in the **IDE** successfully. But my aim is to run is without **IDE**. I can provide the commands that the **IDE** generates during compile and run as provided by my friend.

Comment: Yes exactly ```-L``` was the actual problem. I have added it before the path of ```libbgi.a``` and now my code is running and I am getting the output. Thank you so very much. And please kindly edit your suggested answer and modify it accordingly. After that I will tick mark it as correct.

Comment: Yeah! Definitely, I would switch. But this old library is required for my college practicals on Computer Graphics. That's why seeking the solution was important.